# Why can't I import functions in bert after pip install bert

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I am a beginner for bert, and I am trying to use files of bert given on the GitHub:https://github.com/google-research/bert

However I cannot import files(such as run_classifier, optimisation and so on) from bert after using `pip install bert` to install bert in terminal. I tried to run following codes in jupiter notebook:

```
import bert
from bert import run_classifier
```

And the error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'run_classifier'
```

Then I found the file named 'bert' in `\anaconda3\lib\python3.6\site-packages`, and there were no python files named 'run_classifier', 'optimization' etc inside it. So I downloaded those files from GitHub and put them into file 'bert' by myself. After doing this I could import run_classifier.

However, another problem occurred. I couldn't use the functions inside the files although I could import them.
For example, there's a function `convert_to_unicode` in tokenization.py:

```
Help on module bert.tokenization in bert:

NAME

    bert.tokenization - Tokenization classes.    
FUNCTIONS

    convert_to_unicode(text)
    Converts `text` to Unicode (if it's not already), assuming utf-8 input.
```

Then I tried this:

```
import tokenization from bert
convert_to_unicode('input.txt')
```

And the error is:

```
NameError: name 'convert_to_unicode' is not defined
```

Then I tried:

```
from tokenization import convert_to_unicode
```

And the error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tokenization'
```

I am really confused about this.

Comment: You could also use ```git clone https://github.com/google-research/bert.git``` in order to clone from their git repository!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package you're looking for is `bert-tensorflow`, not `bert`.

[bert-tensorflow](https://pypi.org/project/bert-tensorflow/) is the Python package for Google's BERT implementation.
[bert](https://pypi.org/project/bert) is a serialization library.

Comment: You are right after pip install bert-tensorflow I could use those functions. Thank you so much! By the way I also want to know why I cannot use `from tokenization import convert_to_unicode` instead of `from bert.tokenization import convert_to_unicode`? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try adding these lines of code as in https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hMLd5-r82FrnFnBub-B-fVW78Px4KPX1#scrollTo=2IjSWx7-O8yY
issue is that the BERT embedding is now using TensorFlow 2.0. As TensorFlow 2.0 has been released recently.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.0
!pip install tensorflow_hub
!pip install bert-for-tf2
!pip install sentencepiece

import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
from bert import tokenization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model       # Keras is the new high level API for TensorFlow
import math
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its a new change actually.

```
pip install bert-tensorflow

from bert import bert_tokenization
tokenizer=bert_tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file,do_lower_case)
```